# How to track order of newly created files in directory with fswatch

Tags: bash, macos, file-management, fswatch

I need to monitor a downloads directory, and keep track of the order in which files were written to the directory. The only way I know this is possible in macos is `fswatch`, but the documentation seems quite sparse compared to `inotifywatch` on linux.

For example, if `001.jpg` then `003.jpg` then `002.jpg` were downloaded to the directory (in that order), I would need a variable that looks like this: `001.jpg 003.jpg 002.jpg`

I only need to monitor new files in this case, not modified files. For example, if `001.jpg` is modified, it should not be moved to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash script `handle_order.sh` that will maintain order in the `track_order` text file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "new file is added $1"
filename=$(basename ${1})
echo $filename
if [ $filename != "track_order.txt"  ]; then
echo "${filename}" >> track_order.txt
else
echo "order is updated"
fi
```

`fswatch` command

```
fswatch ./DRS-1.1.0/ --event Created | xargs -I '{}' sh -c './handle_order.sh "$1"' - {}
```

- `(./DRS-1.1.0/)` your directory name which needs to be monitor
- `(handle_order.sh)` bash script that will handle the order and update track_order.txt file
- `(Created)` only create an event

**Updated:**

remove the `handle_order.sh` and run as a single command

```
fswatch ./DRS-1.1.0/ --event Created | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'filename=$(basename ${1});echo $filename;if [ $filename != "track_order.txt"  ]; then echo "${filename}" >> track_order.txt; else echo "order is updated";fi' - {}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but could this be changed to just be a self-contained one-liner (without the need of the external script handle_order.sh)? I don't need an interactive prompt when files are changed, all I would need in this case is a list of filenames in a text file

Comment: Ok, `fswatch <directory> --event Created >> track.txt` is sufficient in this case, but thanks.